# Remove the Qt Online-Installer component

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I have a bunch of components in the Online-Installer and I need to remove one, but I can't figure out how I supposed to do it. As far as I understand, it should be done during the repository generating with the "repogen" utility, but there is no commands to do it. Shall somebody give an advice?

Comment: Shouldn't you run `Qt Maintenance Tool` again and uncheck components you want to remove?

Comment: OK, I think, my explanation wasn't really good. I mean, that I'm creating the Qt online-installer and I need to update it. And the part of this update is to remove one of the components.